# something strange happened when change focus to combobox

Tags: c#

```
  private void _comboClearingCode_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {

        string clearingCodeText = _comboClearingCode.Text;
        //MessageBox.Show(clearingCodeText);
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string item in _comboClearingCode.Items)
        {
            if (clearingCodeText == item)
                break;
            count++;
        }
        if (count == _comboClearingCode.Items.Count)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("please input a valid client code");
            _comboClearingCode.Focus();
        }
    }
```

This event is very simple, when the user input a wrong text, output the error message and return to previous control(in this case the control is combobox). However, it doesn't work as expected, in fact, it output error message twice, in addition, whenever I click the box, it output twice again. It really drives me mad.When I debug the program, I find that when Focus() invoke, it just jump to the validating event immediately, that is why error message output twice. The question is why it just output twice instead of looping?

Comment: To which event is this handler hooked to?

Comment: is the sender different each time?

Comment: i have tried the same code and shows only one message box. is it that you have registered your event twice?

Comment: It is caused by MessageBox + Focus, methods that jerk the focus in an event that's triggered on a focus change.  Don't do that, set e.Cancel = true to prevent the user tabbing out of the control.  Use ErrorProvider for friendly error reporting.

Comment: The case happened when I click a datetimepicker control,  I think the reason may just as Hans Passant had said.